# No disk info in task manager

Tags: windows

I am using a test build of Windows 2016.

When I open Task Manager, I can see CPU, Memory, and Ethernet information.

However, I didn't see Disk info as usual ( in Windows 10 ).

Is it an expected situation?

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot

Comment: I actually just deleted that system, you can imagine that, under the Performance tab, it has CPU, Memory, Ethernet, but no 'Disk'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Disk Counter has been removed from the Performance tab in Windows Server 2012. This is because there is a significant performance impact to collect Disk metrics on a Server due to the overhead Task Manager may cause in querying each Disk IO for each process/disk. Disk metrics are very useful while troubleshooting performance issues on the server. An easy way to check Disk metrics is to use Resource Monitor. Source: Microsoft

To show disk performance metrics in Task Manager

Open the command prompt as administrator and enter following command

`diskperf -Y`

Comment: This works also in 2012R2. But it does not work in Windows 2019, it says it uses some new APIs... (will post the exact text shortly).

Comment: `diskperf` prints:

Both Logical and Physical Disk Performance counters on this system
        are automatically enabled on demand.
For legacy applications using IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE to retrieve raw counters,
you can use -Y or -N to forcibly enable or disable. No restart is required.